# When clicking on a button, the others are also selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I'm trying to create a React application that the user will be able to chose classroom by schedules. He wont be able to choose more than a classrom for schedule. The classroom informations comes from an API which brings the needed data.

When clicking in a classrom, the onclick() receives the information of the choosen classroom and send the *ID* to *choosenClassroom()* function, which turns the classroom selection state as *true*. This state will be the base for the program styling and disable the other classroom alternatives.

Currently, when selecting a classroom (click on the button), every other room are being selected too. Could somebody help me to understand this error please?

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import './Card.css';
import { rooms } from '../../api/rooms';

const Card = () => {

function chosenClassroom(id) {
    const room = rooms.find(room => room.id === id);
    setSelected(true);
  }

const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

  return(
    <Fragment>
  <div className='centralizeContainer'>
    <div className='cardContainer'>
        <h2 className='titleCard'>Select the classrooms</h2>

        <div className='classroomContainer'>
          <div className='schedules'>
            <div className='schedulesText'><h4>09:00</h4></div>
          </div>
          
          <div className='classroomDataContainer'>
            {rooms.map((room) => (
              <div className='classroomData' key={room.id}>
                <button 
                  disabled={selected}
                  className={selected? 'classroomButton selected': 'classroomButton'}
                  onClick={() => chosenClassroom(room.id)}>
                    <p className='classromName'>{room.nome}</p> 
                </button>
                <div className='classroomVacancies'>
                  <h5>{room.vagas} vacancies</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>

          <div className='buttonContainer'>
            <button className='confirmationButton'>
              <p className='buttonText'>Confirm classrooms</p>
            </button>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</Fragment>
  )
}

export default Card
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are enabling button then it will reflect on all buttons because you have only one value for all so try with id based state value as:-

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});
   function chosenClassroom(id) {
        const room = rooms.find(room => room.id === id);
        setSelected({ [id]: true });
      }
```

And use this state in button as:-

```
 <button 
  disabled={selected[room.id]}
  className={selected? 'classroomButton selected': 'classroomButton'}
  onClick={() => chosenClassroom(room.id)}>
  <p className='classromName'>{room.nome}</p> 
 </button>
```

It should work for you.